# Как сверстать слайдер диапазона значений

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, sass

Всем привет!

Столкнулся с проблемой верскти не совсем обычного слайдера диапазона значений.
До сегодняшнего дня  думал, что  умею неплохо верстать, оказалось  это не совсем так :)

Друзья подскажите, как мне  заверстать  такой   элемент. Пробовал через `transform: skewY` с псевдоэлементом ,  но  это  не  лучший  способ,- результат не совсем тот.

В общем, друзья, подтолкните меня  на правильную мысль, или   дайте ссылочку на пример такого  элемента
Спасибо!

[image: range slider]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перетаскивание ползунка уж как-нибудь сами прикрутите

```js
$('[type=number]').on('input',function(){
  $('.range__value').css('background-size', this.value+'% 100%');
  $('.range__btn').css('left',this.value+'%');
})
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:15px;
}
.range{
  position:relative;
  height:20px;
}
.range__inner{
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.range__value{
  height:100%;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,red,green),#ddd;
  background-size:50% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transform:rotate(-1.3deg);
  transform-origin:right center;
}
.range__btn{
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid #bbb;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:#fff;
  border-radius:0 30px 30px 30px;
  position:absolute;
  top:calc(100% + 5px);
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="range">
  <div class="range__inner">
    <div class="range__value"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="range__btn"></div>
</div>
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="50" />
```

Comment: спасибо Вам большое!
Подскажите как нагуглить такой  прогресс  бар?
Я имею ввиду как он правильно  называется.

Comment: Скриптовую часть? Гуглить `range slider`, их много разных, в основном на JQuery.